# how to find fifference between 2 dates in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

In my database I have a TIMESTAMP field.

Now I want to find the difference between the value stored in this field and the current TIMESTAMP, with the result in days.

How can I get it?

**Note: I am using DB2 database**

Answer (score 0):

```
days(TIMESTAMP)_-days(your_col)
```

Comment: thanks for replying but i am geting error with  that.I used
SELECT days(TIMESTAMP) - days(mycol)  FROM DB2ADMIN.tablename ;

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version of DB2 you're using.

In older versions, you have to SELECT against a table, even though you're not retrieving any columns.

```
SELECT days(TIMESTAMP)-days(your_col)
FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES
```

Substitute a creator and table that you have SELECT authority for.

Answer (score 0):

I shall reiterate what Gilbert answered. He was correct, but I don't think the original author understood the idea. As an example:

```
create table test ( mycolumn timestamp )
insert into test values (current timestamp)
select * from test
select days(current timestamp)-days(mycolumn) from test
```

The current timestamp is a special register that DB2 has available. Days is a default function that will return the number of days component of the given timestamp counting from January 1, year 1.

Answer (score 0):

The CURRENT_DATE  returns the current timestamp then this can be used

DAYS(CURRENT_DATE)-DAYS(TIMESTAMP)